# plus-minus (±) sign in regex

Tags: php, regex, utc

I need to produce a regex pattern that verifies UTC offsets.  These are typically formatted as `UTC+05:30` or `UTC-01:00`. It seemed simple enough to match as follows (being permissive for spaces):

`^UTC[ ]?[+\-±][ ]?[01][0-9]:[034][05]$`

[Note: I updated this pattern based on feedback from @barman]

There is a pocket case in which the code is written `UTC±00:00`. However, the plus-minus sign is throwing things off.  Using PHP for example:

```
echo preg_match("/^±$/","±");
echo preg_match("/^[±]$/","±");
echo preg_match("/^[\±]$/","±");
```

Will return `true` for the first match but `false` on the other two.

So my question is, does the `±` require special handling in Regex?  I can't find any reference to this symbol in the docs.  Thx.

Comment: Curious, `preg_match("/[±]/","±")` returns true as well.

Comment: So does `preg_match("/^[±]/","±")` and `preg_match("/[±]$/","±")`

Comment: `var_dump("±")` returns `string(2) "±"` so apparently `±` is a double-byte character. That might be influencing the result of your regex.

Comment: Hum. Good catch @Cully ...  any guidance on how to work around the double-byte challenge?

Comment: the plusminus is part of standard ANSI at decimal 241. There is nothing special about it as far as regex is concerned? Do you have a regex101.com example (set to PHP's parsing) that shows this not working?

Comment: FYI, there's no need to update your question with the answer. It can actually make it confusing to read, since people will interpret it as part of the actual problem. It's normal for people to read the question and then find the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like @Barmar probably solved the first issue you were having (matching the UTC string). However, to explain what you were seeing with:

```php
preg_match("/^±$/","±"); // true
preg_match("/^[±]$/","±"); // false
preg_match("/^[\±]$/","±"); // false
```

The `±` character is two bytes long, so `preg_match` is interpretting it as two characters. In order to match in the way you expect, you have to use the [/u](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) modifier. This tells `preg_match` to treat your pattern as utf-8, which will interpret `±` as a single character instead of two characters.

```php
preg_match("/^[±]$/u","±"); // true
```

And to include an example that matches your UTC sample:

```php
// with the /u modifier (works as expected)
preg_match("/^UTC[ ]?[+\-±][ ]?[01][0-9]:[034][05]$/u", "UTC±05:30"); // true

// without the /u modifier (does not match)
preg_match("/^UTC[ ]?[+\-±][ ]?[01][0-9]:[034][05]$/", "UTC±05:30"); // false
```

Answer (score 2):

You mustn't put the `-` between two characters inside `[]`, that makes it create a range (like when you write `[0-9]`) rather than matching the `-` character literally.

You should put the `-` at the beginning or end, or escape it.

```
^UTC[ ]?[+\-±][ ]?[01][0-9]:[034][05]$
```

Also, you don't put `|` inside `[]` character sets. That's used inside `()` to create alternative patterns.

Comment: Thanks.  Yes, excellent points.  I am newish to Regex.  So I tried your pattern as `echo preg_match("/^UTC[ ]?[+\-±][ ]?[01][0-9]:[034][05]$/","UTC ±00:00");` and it still returns false.

Comment: It works here: https://regex101.com/r/mdfBbz/1